# Why is the impurity level in a semiconductor related to the ionization energy of the carrier?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals

I am using Kittel's book. It says that the relationship between the distance of donor level to the bottom of conduction band is related to the ionization energy, but it does not say why.

Comment: This distance represents the energy needed to.....? What happens when a conduction band electron absorbs more energy than that binding it to the solid?

Comment: The book is correct. Think of what it means for us to say that a carrier is ionised in the context of a semiconductor? Be reminded that in condensed matter physics we are often thinking about infinitely large crystals. i.e. the infinitely large universe only has this crystal, no empty space anywhere.

Comment: Ionization means the delocalization of the electron from the donor so that it shall move freely in the crystal, right? But I still cannot comprehend the relationship between impurity level and ionization energy.

Comment: The distance mentioned above is the energy needed to move the electron into the conduction band. Ionization means the electron is liberated from the crystal completely.  That is, the crystal becomes ionized, hence "ionization energy".

Answer (score 0):

The ionization energy for an intrinsic semiconductor is the sum of the energy gap plus the energy required to remove the electron from the conduction band completely from the crystal. The impurities (donors or acceptors) present a lower energy source of electrons/holes.
For conductivity to increase:

$$ E_{gap} > E_{donor-ionization} $$
where $$E_{donor-ionization} =  E_{conduction} - E_{donor}$$

and $$E_{gap} = E_{conduction} - E_{valence}$$

With impurities $$E_{ionization} = E_{donor-ionization} + E_{removal-from-semiconductor}$$

This is how impurity levels are related to ionization energy